# How to decompile obfuscated Python code?

Tags: decompilation, python, deobfuscation, executable, decompile

I have an executable file, which I am trying to decompile. I have already deduced that it was originally programmed in Python. I know that it was obfuscated with [PyArmor](https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor) and possibly compiled with [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller). I have tried multiple attempts at finding the source code, such as:

- Using CheatEngine to read the memory
- Using IDA to read assembler code
- Using multiple PyInstaller unpackers to get source code

But all of them, to no avail. Is there any way I can get the source code of this file, and if so, how?

Here's the Stack Trace I got when I terminated the program with `CTRL + C`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<dist/obf\bot.py>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen bot>", line 798, in <module>
  File "<frozen keyvalidation>", line 243, in checkStuff
  File "<frozen keyvalidation>", line 150, in checkKey
  File "site-packages\requests\api.py", line 116, in post
  File "site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
  File "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 360, in connect
  File "site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 850, in _create
  File "ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
KeyboardInterrupt
[36076] Failed to execute script bot
```

Comment: it's more likely that it only contains no source code but instead python bytecode that you will need to find and decompile

Comment: How exactly did you deduce that "it was originally programmed in Python"?

Comment: Using `CTRL + C`, I managed to crash the program. The error message matches that of one Python would spit out.

Comment: i think the possible way it's dump process with "Windows Process Explorer". But i don't know how extract deobfuscated bytecode from dump

Answer (score 1):

From the “frozen” text in the stack trace, it was probably processed with cx_Freeze or a similar tool. Usually they put the compiled Python files into a zip file embedded into the executable, so try looking for one (e.g. with binwalk)